# Overwrite Global CSS style

Tags: css

I have a global css style for buttons in my main css file, but I need to have a different color on a certain page.

I have tried the !important on a new class name on the specific page, but it does not work unless i remove the main css file (link).

I have a CSS style for buttons as follows:

```
   /* Style the submit button with a specific background color GREEN etc */
   input[type=button] {
   background-color: #4CAF50;
   color: white;
   padding: 12px 20px;
   font-size: 16px;
   border: none;
   border-radius: 5px;
   cursor: pointer;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   }
```

I want to use a different background color (red) until the button is pushed and then change it to green.

Comment: `!important` carries the maximum level of specificity. Your selector is likely either invalid or you've cached the old styles. The other scenario is that your main CSS has an `!important` declaration in itself, so the declarations tie each other out, and your main CSS file is loaded last. Can you adjust you HTML to load the main CSS before your additional CSS?

Comment: Could you please provide more context to the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Do you know the conflicting style in the main CSS? If so, please share it in your post. Also, make sure you do a hard refresh with command+r of both the displayed html and any external css file.

Comment: Use the developer tools in the browser of your choice (usually F12) to inspect the element on the new page to inspect the element. This will show you what styles are being applied and what styles are being overridden and by what. Also please show both versions of the CSS, the relevant parts of the main CSS and what you are using to over ride

Comment: What exactly is supposed to happen on the screen? There is no CSS that can distinguish between a button that hasn't been clicked yet and a button that has. Unless you mean while the button is actually being depressed and/or focused.

Comment: I wound up changing from a button to a link that is styled to look like a button.  I could not get the button do be a different color (change class) once the input [type=button] is set.  I can not get the link to change from red to green with javascript once the link is clicked on .

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try to write inline css it will be work.
    on particular page




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=reset] {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Styled input buttons.</p>

<input type="button" value="Button">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you expand this example into a snippet that demonstrates the solution?

Comment: can you add your html?

Comment: Check now full example

Comment: also check below link 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_buttons_color

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options - order - last CSS wins or be more specific for example...

```css
div > input[type=button],
div > input[type=submit],
div > input[type=reset] {
  background-color: red;
}

input[type=button],
input[type=submit],
input[type=reset] {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Styled input buttons.</p>

<input type="button" value="Button">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

<hr>
<div>
  <input type="button" value="Button">
  <input type="reset" value="Reset">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
```

You can also find nice path by copy JS path in Dev Tools and remove IDs or something you do not want to use.

document.querySelector("**body > input[type=button]:nth-child(2)**")